# Select events count exept weekends oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

again. I hope that I havent got tired of me.
My query is:

```
select round((trunc(action_dt)-to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy'))*24*60*60*1000)  as action_dt, count(*) as cnt
from stat.jurnal_orders
where action_dt between TO_DATE('$begDate','DD/MM/YY') AND TO_DATE('$endDate','DD/MM/YY')
group by trunc(action_dt)
order by action_dt asc
```

It counts the number of events per one day.

```
18.03.05    1
18.03.05    4
18.03.05    4
25.03.05    2
25.03.05    2
25.03.05    1
```

Like that. But the thing is that I dont want to include weekends in my query! Weakends are SATURDAY AND SUNDAY(russia, lol)(sorry, guys)
Can you help me?

Comment: Someone with Russian family disagrees with your definition of weekend... what part of Russia do you live in? :D

Answer (score 4):

```
where to_char(action_dt, 'DY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') not in ('SAT', 'MON')
```

Comment: Better add some nls parameters like this `to_char(action_dt, 'DY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') not in ('SAT', 'MON')` (doesn't have to be american of course..)